# No connections to bridge

Tags: bridge, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I set up a bridge at home on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Buster) using [these instructions](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/), and I believe everything is configured correctly... But there is no activity in or out of my bridge. Here's some messages I am seeing:

> 16:31:26 [NOTICE] Heartbeat: In the last 6 hours, I have seen 0 unique clients. [2 duplicates hidden]
>
> 16:31:26 [NOTICE] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 17:59 hours, with 0 circuits open. I've sent 6.18 MB and received 25.58 MB. [2 duplicates hidden]
>
> 16:04:28 [NOTICE] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
>
> 13:10:43 [NOTICE] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 408 (a Testing circuit 3-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 60000ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out

I know bridges don't see as much activity but is this abnormal? Also since I am behind a router, specifically what ports would have to be forwarded?

Comment: You can try to connect to your own bridge with the standard Tor browser to check if it is working. I possible, test this from another WAN connection so that you can be sure NAT is working as well (if that applies).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions for debian:
https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/

About ports, it says:

> Don't forget to change the ORPort, ServerTransportListenAddr,
>   ContactInfo, and Nickname options.
>
> If you decide to use a fixed obfs4 port smaller than 1024 (for example
>   80 or 443), you will need to give obfs4 CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
>   capabilities to bind the port with a non-root user:
>
> sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/obfs4proxy

Pretty much, pick a port and make sure that it is open on your router.

From the [Tor Relay Guide](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide) we see:

> The IPv4 address is not required to be static but static IP addresses
>   are preferred. Your IPv4 address should remain unchanged for at least
>   3 hours (if it regularly changes more often than that, it does not
>   make much sense to run a relay or bridge there since it takes time to
>   distribute the new list of relay IPs to clients - which happens only
>   once every hour).

also, check [here](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search) for your bridge. Do you see any errors or warnings?

Finally, there is a [tor-relays](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-relays/) mailing list with other people who are running relays, bridges, etc.

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide